# Why does the DHC-6 have only one set of elevator cables?

Tags: safety, flight-controls, elevator, dhc-6, redundancy

[Air Moorea Flight 1121](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Moorea_Flight_1121) crashed because its up-elevator cable broke, allowing the elevator to blow to its faired position and thus be unavailable to counteract the pitch-down moment caused by the flaps being retracted;<sup>1</sup> the DHC-6 elevator control system has two cables (up-elevator and down-elevator, distinguished by what part of the aft-quadrant bellcrank they attach to), and, if one breaks, the tension in both is released and the elevator floats.  No redundancy is provided in the form of a second or third set of elevator cables, unlike how most airliners have double- or even triple-redundant flight controls.  Why does the DHC-6 have only a single set of elevator control cables, rather than two or three?

---

<sup>1</sup>: No matter that [retracting one’s flaps should not do that](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60749/why-does-the-dhc-6-pitch-down-when-the-flaps-are-retracted-rather-than-up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twin Otter isn't certified in a category that requires duplicate control runs with split surfaces.  It's more or less a single engine Otter with two PT-6s and a redesigned tail.  Those requirements apply to heavier aircraft than the DHC-6.

Comment: If it were a one-person general-aviation aircraft, I'd buy that explanation, but this is an _airliner_ we're talking about here (albeit a small one).

Comment: The Beech 1900 is the Twin Otter's closest competitor in the commuter airline business, and it also has a single cable circuit.  You don't see separate left and right elevator control systems with pitch disconnects until you are in the Transport Category airplanes of the Dash 8/ATR size.

Comment: @Sean doesn't matter. The requirements are based on aircraft size, weight, etc. and not so much the purpose it's used for.